# Finite coefficients Langlands for function fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-conjectures, function-fields

Do we have a finite coefficients Langlands correspondence for function fields? By which I mean a bijection between Galois representations $$\pi_1(X)\to \mathrm{GL}_n\left(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}\right)$$
and "mod $p$" automorphic forms, where $X$ is a smooth projective curve over a finite field (presumably there is a distinction to be made if $p$ is the characteristic of $X$ or not, but I'm interested in either case). I'm sure there is a nice survey on this question out there, if you could point in the right direction that'd be great!

Comment: Good question, but as Langlands' geometric philosophy dictates, we should (perhaps?) ask it for locally constant residual $p$-adic sheaves instead of mod $p$ automorphic forms.

Comment: @MarsaultChabat (perhaps) Indeed. I genuinely don't know what to expect. I just decided to say mod p automorphic forms because one would probably like to have some functoriality, in particular between p-adic and mod p coefficients